# String not comparing correct in if statement in iphone app

Tags: iphone, if-statement, comparison

I have string which shows following ling in NSLog when i compare this it always runs else

Records inserted: -1

How to make it works if data is equal to the given text other wise run else

```
        NSLog(@"%@ ",data);


if ([data isEqualToString:@"Records inserted: -1"]) {


    NSString*messageShow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title name %@ already been added to Library",titleNameShow];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:messageShow delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];


}

else {



NSString*messageShow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ added to Library",titleNameShow];



UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:messageShow delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
```

Comment: what is "`data`" declared as?  a NSData or NSString object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure there are no white spaces in `NSStrind* data`?

try;

```
NSLog(@"|%@|",data);
```

and check returned string, it should be: |Records inserted: -1|

Comment: dang it, I was typing the exact same thing from the exact same thought...  you got to it faster than me, so +1 to you.

Comment: LOL... well, i was commenting something like your comment... that was my second option/suspect... thats why i especially added "NSStrind* data" in my answer... +1 to your comments

Comment: | Records inserted: -1 | result of NSLOg of your data is like thi s

Comment: well... then you've got the answer... " Records inserted: -1 " is never equal to "Records inserted: -1"

Comment: do u really need to remove spaces? isn't it faster to add them to the comparison string: if ([data isEqualToString:@" Records inserted: -1 "])...

Comment: i have remove the string fron NSString which comes from server like this 2013-06-19 14:54:56.717 ProductivoApp[9439:c203]  Recordsinserted:-1 this is the log of data now but again it does not work

Comment: Ali... your <if code> is correct... now it's up to you to know what the string should contain to check that <if code>, "Recordsinserted:-1", " Records inserted: -1 ", or "Records inserted: -1"... no one else could help you in this!